# What is the most efficient way of addressing an element in XPath?

Tags: java, xml, xpath, axiom

I have a Java program which cares about efficiency. There I use XPaths.

In XPath I can select elements starting from root

```
/root/a/b/c/d/e
```

or use the `descendent-or-self` axis:

```
//e
```

What will be most efficient method among these two?

Answer (score 3):

A direct path will tend to perform better than one using the more general descendant-or-self (`//`) axis, however:

- Implementations *could* vary (but as a general rule, direct paths perform better).
- The difference can be minor enough not to matter, especially for
  small documents.
- As with all performance concerns, measure before optimizing to avoid expending effort in areas other than true bottlenecks.

Comment: In the specific case of a _leading_ `//` I wouldn't be surprised if many processors can optimise this to a single hash table lookup. The final bullet is definitely the key - don't guess, _measure_.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that /root/a/b/c/d/e would be more efficient, because in the first case, the XPath processor can eliminate a lot of branches, whereas in the second case (//e) the XPath processor has to search the entire document tree.

You should write a small Java program that excersizes the two different ways, and then see how long it takes to run 1000 loops.

Answer (score 1):

Understanding the leading `/` and `//` constructs is very important.

A leading `/` starts a path that is always relevant to the root node. Therefore, even though we are searching a sub-node, the XPath:

```
root/a/b/c
```

...  will still return every `c` node in your XML document even though they are not descendants of the first `c` node. Likewise, the XPath:

```
//e/
```

... will still return every `e` node in your XML document, not just the descendants of your first `c` node.